# Relationships in mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I've written some simple program with golang and mgo. My question is how to properly to relationships in mgo.

**1st Approach:**

```
type User struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Username string          `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    Email    string          `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Password string          `json:"password" bson:"password"`
    Friends  []User          `json:"friends" bson:"friends"`
}
```

"**Friends**" is a slice of Users. I can $push a pointer to a User and it just works fine. The thing is that I only want to store a reference to the user and not nesting it:

**2nd Approach:**

```
type User struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Username string          `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    Email    string          `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Password string          `json:"password" bson:"password"`
    Friends  []bson.ObjectId `json:"friends" bson:"friends"`
}
```

This gives me the output I want - but now it's not visible from the struct which nested structs are referenced. Does mgo provide some mechanism to deal with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mgo is a db driver library and not an ORM.. 
What I'd do is have the ids array as in the 2nd example (unexported, with lowercase) and have a Friends() method which queries the db by those ids and return a []User